# Generating Numbers in sequence

Tags: c#, linq

How can i generate numbers using LinQ in this sequence given the startIndex,count of numbers and the maximum number.For example:

```
Sample Numbers = 1,2,3,4

StartIndex = 1 (i.e it should start from 1)
Sequence number count = 3 
Maximum number = 4 (i.e till 4)

Expected result given the above details :
 1,2,3
 1,3,4
 1,2,4
```

Is there a way to do it using  linQ?

Comment: In other words, are you looking to generate the set of all sequences consisting of StartIndex followed by a permutation of (StartIndex+1..Max choose Count)?

Comment: You should look up how to list all permutations of a list.

Comment: This site might help. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Combinatorics.aspx

Comment: Are you making the problem more difficult by restricting the solution to Linq?

Comment: No not restricted to LinQ, I just wanted it to be in C#. Start index is from where the number should start in a sequence. To give you another example.1,2,3,4,5,6,7 are the numbers i have in a variable. My start Index is 2 and sequenceCount = 3, here the max number is 7.When my start Index is 2 then for every result returned should contain "2".It means the numbers starts from 2. So my expected result for the sample provided in this description as follows: 2,3,4 - 2,4,5 - 2,5,6 - 2,6,7 and 2,3,7 .I have used "-" as delimiter to show different resultset.

Comment: @user720581 - why would it not contain 2,3,5 - 2,3,6 - 2,4,6 - 2,4,7 and 2,5,7?

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't need the length of you sequences to be dynamic, then you could use:

```
var startindex=1;
var maxindex=4;

var data = Enumerable.Range(startindex,maxindex);
var qry = from x in data
          where x == startindex
          from y in data
          where x < y
          from z in data
          where y < z
          select new { x, y, z };
foreach (var tuple in qry) {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", tuple.x, tuple.y, tuple.z);
}
```

The sequence length is hardcoded to 3, because there are 3 enumerables being joined: x, y, z.

If you want to dynamically join an arbitrary number of enumerables, then you can use [Eric Lippert's Cartesian Product Linq example.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx)

You pass a set of k sequences of N items, and it will return a set of all combinations of length k.

Now, you don't want repeated elements in your results.
So, I added the following to Eric's example:

```
where accseq.All(accitem => accitem < item)
```

Here's the final solution (edited for clarity):

```
var startindex=1;
var maxindex=7;
var count = 3;

// Make a set of count-1 sequences, whose values range from startindex+1 to maxindex
List<List<int>> sequences = new List<List<int>>();

// We only want permutations starting with startindex.  So, the first input sequence to be joined should only have the value startindex.
List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
list1.Add(startindex);
sequences.Add(list1);

// The rest of the input sequences to be joined should contain the range startindex+1 .. maxindex
for (int i=1; i< count; i++)
{
 sequences.Add(Enumerable.Range(startindex+1,maxindex-startindex).ToList());
}

// Generate the permutations of the input sequences
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> emptyProduct = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<int>() };
var result = sequences.Aggregate( 
    emptyProduct, 
    (accumulator, sequence) =>  
      from accseq in accumulator  
      from item in sequence
      where accseq.All(accitem => accitem < item)
      select accseq.Concat(new[] {item}));                

// Show the result
foreach (var x in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay in response. @mbeckish, your solution was too close but i guess my explanation was not clear.Ok, let me explain again.When i want numbers till 7 we give Enumerable.Range(1,7) gives us numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.Out of these numbers i want to have one as the index number and get the sequences with maximum sequential numbers with all possible combinations.Example.Say from 1-7, Index is 3,max Sequential count is 3.Then my combinations will be 3,4,5 - 3,5,6 - 3,6,7 - 3,7,1 and 3-2-1.Then next sequence will not be valid because Index repeats."-" Delimiter is for understanding purpose

Comment: @SharpC - Your comment does not match the problem description.  For example, in the problem description you list 1,2,4 as one of the sequences in the solution.  However, 2 and 4 are not sequential.  I think you need to start from scratch and carefully word the problem description.

Comment: @mbeckish thanks for the suggestion.I'll rephrase the problem statement again.

Comment: In a list of sequential numbers say from 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.I want to find all the combinations using parameters like for ex: StartNumber=5,max number of numbers to retrieve=3. From the solution you provided if it reaches the last number I.e 7 it doesn't go back because 5,1,2 -5,2,3 and 5,4,5(the last resultset  can't be considered valid coz the startIndex repeats.) Are also valid.so the final expected output are 5,6,7-5,7,1-5,2,3 and 5,4,5(last is invalid).For each resultset separated by delimiter "-" it skips one number example if u look at 5,6,7 and 5,7,1 "6" is skipped in the next resultset.

Comment: @SharpC - I'm sorry, I don't understand your latest comment at all.  You only list 4 sequences in your results (5,6,7),(5,7,1),(5,2,3),(5,4,5). But I don't think you really mean there should only be 4 sequences in the result, or do you?  Can you give us another example, and explicitly list all of the sequences that you would expect to see in the results?

Comment: @mbeckish thank you for your support.Actually i had to work on two solutions to solve permutating an array of arrays with multiple reverse operators.The question posted here was one of the solution i was working on.Fortunately i got the 2nd solution working well for my problem statement.Once again Thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

Try this function.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permute<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)
        {
            if (list.Count() == 1)
                return new List<IEnumerable<T>> { list };

            return list.Select((a, i1) => Permute(list.Where((b, i2) => i2 != i1)).Select(b => (new List<T> { a }).Union(b)))
                       .SelectMany(c => c);
        }
```

//Here Range(startindex, count)

```
List<int> list1 = Enumerable.Range(1, 3).ToList();
```

//generates all permutations

```
var permutationlist = Permute(list1);
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first let's state the problem clearly. I'll assume your numbers are `int` but that's a mostly irrelevant detail but the concreteness makes thinking go more smo

You have a sequence `a_0, a_1, a_2, ..., a_N` of `int`.

You have an integer `k` satisfying `1 <= k <= N + 1`.

You have a starting index `start >=0` and an ending index `end <= N`.

You want all subsequences `a_i0, a_i1, a_i2, ..., a_ik` of length `k` such that `i0 = start` and `ik = end`.

Then your algorithm is simple. You want to produce all combinations of size `k - 2` of `{ start + 1, ..., end - 1 }`. Given such a combination `j1, j2, ..., j(k-1)`, order it, call the resulting ordered sequence `i1, i2, ..., i(k-1)` and return the sequence `a_start, a_i1, a_i2, ..., a_i(k-1), a_end`.

Now that you know a formal statement of the problem, and what you need to solve it, resources abound for generating said combinations. cf. [Google search : Generating combinations C#](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=generating+combinations+c%23) or [Knuth Volume 4A](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201038048).

Comment: You'll find that if you can learn how to state your problems clearly and formally, it will eliminate a lot of confusion when other people read your problem statements.

Comment: @Downvoter: I would love to know why this was downvoted. Either it's wrong and you should leave a helpful comment saying why, it's right but not helpful in which case you should elaborate why, or it's right and helpful in which case you made a mistake.

Comment: Jason, I think some maniac just down voted all of us in one shot.